# Does anyone have suggestions for dog treats similar to sweet potato?

Tags: dogs, treats

My dog is very "food motivated".  We have tried many different treats, with the goal of finding something that will keep her occupied for a while.  She has no interest in rawhide chews or Nylabone.

Her favorite treat is Golden Rewards - Sweet Potato wrapped with Chicken.  Those are like candy to her, and they take a minute or so for her to chew up.

Any suggestions for something that is somewhat sweet, like sweet potato, but takes longer to chew up?

Comment: Do you have a preference on whether you want to buy them or make them yourself?

Comment: @BriHan I prefer to buy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were wanting to purchase them, there are some great options online:

These ring shaped ones by Good Lovin' could take her a bit longer to chew:
[www.petco.com](http://www.petco.com)

Smartbones Large Sweet potato Chews at Chewy:
[www.chewy.com](http://www.chewy.com)

Then there are these SmartSticks Chews:
[www.petsmart.com](http://www.petsmart.com)

The direct links are incredible long and I don't want to get in trouble for spam on here. But they are easy to find at those websites and all of them should take your dog a bit longer to consume.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To avoid spam and be ingormative for all over the world, you could include pictures of the treats. So anybody gets an imagination of it and can choose the brand by oneself.